# How can I find all the db triggers in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, database-trigger

I created a trigger using SQL, how can I see the trigger using MySQL in phpMyadmin?

Comment: It's annoying that it doesn't have another tab "triggers"

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a tool, not a database

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Click on the 'SQL' tab and enter this query:

```
SHOW TRIGGERS
```

Comment: You can use mysqldump with --triggers switch http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: Or you can use Database Backup or Gen.Schema Script in dbForge Studio for MySQL.

Comment: mysqldump backs up triggers by default: "--triggers

Include triggers for each dumped table in the output. This option is enabled by default;"

Answer (score 5):

```
select * from information_schema.triggers where trigger_schema = 'your_db'
```

Comment: There are commands to manage a database schema other than interacting directly with the information_schema database such as SHOW TRIGGERS which should be preferred.

Comment: Is this the best way if you want to create a view of your triggers? SHOW TRIGGERS is not valid in "AS" for create view.

Answer (score 1):

to see all your routines the code is...

```
select * from information_schema.routines
```