# How to Edit Trigger in phpmyadmin in XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I can't find out how to view the  TRIGGER in XAMPP phpmyadmin? can somebody help me with this? where I can find the trigger code in phpmyadmin?

thanks.

Comment: https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Trigger

Answer (score 2):

You can edit trigers on `Triggers` tab in database. For example see [demo server](http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/db_triggers.php?db=sakila&table=&server=2).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display existing TRIGGERS (without editing them), you can enter one of the following commands in phpMyAdmin's SQL tab:

```
`SHOW TRIGGERS`
```

or

```
SELECT * from information_schema.triggers WHERE trigger_schema = 'your_db'
```

Comment: Note that the answer the original post by ChocoMartin is a duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420812/how-can-i-find-all-the-db-trigger-in-mysql) where these answers were already provided. Unfortunately, I could not comment the original message.